# Are there courses about complex dapp development?

Tags: solidity, dapp-development

I've followed a lot of tutorials about dapp development (most of them are lotteries and ballot projects). There were good introductions to SC and Solidity development but I wanted to know if there are some good real courses about complexe dapp development?

I understand how a SC works but I now need to understand how applications like Gab, Minds, Odysee are using blockchain to work and how they can reward their users with some crypto currencies.

Comment: The best course is to participate in those projects, many are open source and you can follow their development.

Comment: Not my question

Comment: I'm not aware of any. As this space is still in its infancy, many people just rush to ship a new products and learn as they go. I would agree with @Ismael, that the best thing right now is to pick a few opensource projects and read through them or even participate.
Also I would suggest to go through some interactive games focused on security, one can learn some advanced concepts from them and learn from mistakes made by others.

https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/
https://www.damnvulnerabledefi.xyz/